# How to add an item with the button that can delete this item c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, button, addition

Im trying to make an app that adds shopping items with the price(just for education purpose). I want to add a button as well so that I can delete this item if I want too. this is what Ive done:
[image]

```
class ShopItem
{

    string name;
    decimal price;
    int labelNumber;

    public ShopItem(string name, decimal price, int labelNumber)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.labelNumber = labelNumber;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public decimal GetPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public int GetLabelNumber()
    {
        return labelNumber;
    }
}
```

Then in my main class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<ShopItem> shopItems = new List<ShopItem>();
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    List<Label> labelsList = new List<Label>();
    int shopItemNumber;
    int top = 50;
    int left = 50;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.shopItemNumber = shopItems.Count;
        label3.Text = "";
        label3.Text = shopItemNumber.ToString();
        shopItems.Add(new ShopItem(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text), shopItemNumber));
        AddLabel();
        AddAButton();
    }

    void AddAButton()
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        buttons.Add(newButton);
        newButton.Left = left + 100;
        newButton.Top = top;
        newButton.Text = "DELETE";
        panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
        top += 40;
    }

    void AddLabel()
    {
        Label newLabel = new Label();
        labelsList.Add(newLabel);
        newLabel.Left = left;
        newLabel.Top = top;
        newLabel.Text = shopItems[shopItemNumber].GetName() + " " + shopItems[shopItemNumber].GetPrice();
        panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    }
}
```

Im adding new objects and then checking the list count so that I know each item number. Now I dont know how to make buttons to remove each item. I would also like to know what is the best practice for this type of tasks? I dont want to use database as its too complicated for now, just make it in runtime? How would you, advanced guys, would make it?

I managed to do something like this based on your answers:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<ShopItem> shopItems = new List<ShopItem>();
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    List<Label> labelsList = new List<Label>();
    int shopItemID;
    int top = 50;
    int left = 50;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        shopItemID = 0;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int shopItemID = this.shopItemID;
        label3.Text = "";
        label3.Text = shopItemID.ToString();

        decimal price;
        if(Decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text.Replace(",", "."), out price))
        {
            shopItems.Add(new ShopItem(textBox1.Text, price, shopItemID));
            label3.Text = price.ToString();
            AddLabel();
            AddAButton();
            this.shopItemID++;
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = "Wrong price format provided";
        }
    }

    void AddAButton()
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        buttons.Add(newButton);
        newButton.Left = left + 100;
        newButton.Top = top;
        newButton.Text = "DELETE";
        panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
        top += 40;
        newButton.Tag = this.shopItemID;
        newButton.Click += DeleteClicked;
    }

    void DeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        int itemNumber = (int)button.Tag;
        ShopItem item = shopItems[itemNumber];
        button.Dispose();
        labelsList[itemNumber].Dispose();
    }

    void AddLabel()
    {
        Label newLabel = new Label();
        labelsList.Add(newLabel);
        newLabel.Left = left;
        newLabel.Top = top;
        newLabel.Text = shopItems[shopItemID].GetName() + " " + shopItems[shopItemID].GetPrice();
        newLabel.Tag = this.shopItemID;
        panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    }
}
```

It's working as I wanted it. The question is: The way I did it was according to the right coding practice?
The other question is: I would like to add placement functionality so that if some item is deleted other items go up the way. Should I use some position list? Can All of those items be contained within a ShopItem class? I mean, can I add button, label and other stuff withing this class so they all are created at the same time and becomes one object?

Comment: About data storage, as this application is for educational use only with no confidential data so you can use XML file to save your data in plain and organized textual form.

Comment: A DataGridView would handle this better.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to identify what Label belongs to the button.

Make AddLabel return the label it just created:

```
Label AddLabel()
{
    Label newLabel = new Label();
    labelsList.Add(newLabel);
    newLabel.Left = left;
    newLabel.Top = top;
    newLabel.Text = shopItems[shopItemNumber].GetName() + " " + shopItems[shopItemNumber].GetPrice();
    panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    return newLabel;
}
```

Pass the label to the new button, and add code to remove it. Store the current shopItem in a variable, so you can access it from the removal code.

```
void AddAButton(Label newLabel)
{
    Button newButton = new Button();
    buttons.Add(newButton);
    newButton.Left = left + 100;
    newButton.Top = top;
    newButton.Text = "DELETE";
    panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
    top += 40;

    // Store the current shopItem in the context (for the lambda)
    var shopItem = shopItems[shopItemNumber]  

    newButton.Click += (s, e) => {
       panel1.Controls.Remove(newLabel);
       panel1.Controls.Remove(newButton);
       newLabel.Dispose();
       newButton.Dispose();
       shopItems.Remove(shopItem);
    }
}
```

Since controls are IDisposable, it is advised to call Dispose after removing them.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you'll want to do is start using IDs instead of the count. The reason is, let's say you have 5 items (0 through 4) and you delete one. Now when you add another new one, it will get #4 because the count is 4 again (before adding the new one to the list), which means you'll have two #4s.

What you'll want to do instead is something like look for the highest existing number and add 1 to it:

```
this.shopItemNumber = shopItems.Any() ? shopItems.Max(item => item.labelNumber) + 1 : 0;
```

Now for the Delete button, just pass the item's number to the `AddAButton()` method:

```
AddAButton(shopItemNumber);
```

...and change the method's signature accordingly:

```
void AddAButton(int itemNumber)
```

And then in the `AddAButton()` method, add that number to the `Tag` property (you'll see why below):

```
newButton.Tag = itemNumber;
```

You'll also need to subscribe to the button's `Click` event:

```
newButton.Click += DeleteClicked;
```

Then create the `DeleteClicked()` method. This is where you'll make use of that `Tag` property:

```
void DeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    int itemNumber = (int)button.Tag;

    ShopItem item = shopItems.FirstOrDefault(item => item.labelNumber = itemNumber);
    if (item != null)
        shopItems.Remove(item);
}
```

You'll also want to clean up the controls. Make sure to `Dispose()` them after removing them.